# refresh out of date eclipse warnings

Tags: java, eclipse, refresh, warnings

I have a warning in my Java code that I fixed.  However, it remains in the "Problems" view.  I can't figure out how to get eclipse to refresh it.  It's even highlighting the wrong line (it's an unchecked cast, and it's displaying on the method header line)

I'm using eclipse 3.7.2 with the android development kit and the git plugin installed in the workspace, although this project is not an android project.

The project does not have a builder associated with it; I am building at the command line.  I have cleaned and rebuilt everything and refreshed the project.

I've also tried removing org.eclipse.jdt.core and org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects//.indexes, and I've tried closing and re-opening the project.

Any suggestions?

Comment: right click on the warning and Delele?

Comment: ah, thanks.  Never would have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Does the "Source" column of the problems view say "Android lint" for this warning, even though it is no Android project? If so, please upgrade the Android Development Tools plugin to the current version. In ADT 20.0.2 a bug was fixed which held outdated Java warnings/errors active even after fixing them.

Comment: There is no "Source" column, but I'm at ADT version 20.0.3 anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

See suggestion by original requester in comments for [How to update warnings in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194026/how-to-update-warnings-in-eclipse)

"Take a look in the 'Problems' view and delete the warnings manually."

Once the 'stuck' warnings are deleted normal Eclipse service should resume.