# How to update warnings in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings, checkstyle

I am using Eclipse Juno for a Java project. I have activated different warnings in my workspace settings. Furthermore I use Checkstyle with a defined rule set for each project.
The problem I am facing now is that Eclipse shows warnings (not sure, if Checkstyle or Java warnings) and does not update the warnings anymore, when I change code. E.g. I have warnings in empty lines referring to code in other lines.

I already tried the following things:

- Refresh with F5
- Building the projects
- Project clean
- Checkstyle settings: Refresh cashed checkstyle configurations
- Restarting Eclipse with "-clean" to clean my workspace
- Project close/open

Does anyone have another tip on how to solve the issue?

Comment: Try reinstalling eclipse.

Comment: background compilation should happen continuously but sometimes it behaves differently, whenever you save code it will try to recompile... try Ctrl+S

Comment: Ctrl+S does not work, Reinstalling Eclipse might work, but it will be the last thing I will try...

Comment: Under 'Project' is 'Build Automatically' ticked?

Comment: Yes, 'Build Automatically' is activated.

Comment: Take a look in the 'Problems' view and try deleting them manually... may not actually solve the cause of the problem

Comment: @Edd: Thank you, manually deleting the problems and running Checkstyle again solved the problem. Now updates work, whenever I change and save code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look in the 'Problems' view and delete the warnings manually

Comment: I recently ran into this problem with Eclipse Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0). Removing all warnings and info messages and manually executing "clean" on all projects solved the issue (from 400 errors to around 30).